# Why do I not have a C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps folder?

Tags: windows, clickonce, special-folders

I am trying to install a ClickOnce application and it is not working. I am told to delete the C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 folder. However I do not even have a C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps folder. I have tried just creating a folder named 'Apps' there and then starting the application but I still get the same error.

Why does my computer not have a C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps folder?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to check "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Roaming" and not "Local". You can see your appdata folder by typing "%appdata% in start -> run.

Comment: I looked in the "Roaming" folder as well but there was no "App" folder or "ClickOnce" folder there. I was suggested to reinstall the .NET framework to see if that would help but it did not. When you run a "ClickOnce" app, it is suppose to create an "App" folder in your "Local" folder, but it doesn't do that on mine, it only creates a "Deployment" folder with no other folders or files in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hidden folder. Make sure that you have set your folder options to show all hidden folders, otherwise you will not see it.